# Laravel Route for JSON Response Views

Tags: ajax, laravel, routes

I have some views which return data of my Models with `toJSON()`.

Is it possible (using 5.3) to make those unavaiable for normal users, but reachable for AJAX requests?

I've seen that there is an api.php routes-file but those seem to need the `auth:api` middlerwares, and I don't want them to need a api-key or something because the route is called by my application itself using twitter typeahead.

Comment: how do you define `normal user`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Mandeep Gill already mentioned you can check if the request is coming from ajax:

```
function myFunction() {
    if (!Request::ajax()) {
        return;
    }

    // Include logic here and define data
    $data = '';

    return response()->json($data, 200);
}
```

However, I'd suggest you to create a private API that your application can use.

Comment: As @Gadzhev says, it is worth separating your routes and maybe even controllers into API specific namespaces. This will make handling your requests a lot neater.

Comment: Do you have a starting point for a private API in laravel, or a short tutorial?

Answer (score 1):

Where you are returning result return like this :

```
if(\Request::ajax()) {

  return \Response::make(["data" => $data]); // return what you likes

} else {

  return view('test'); // For normal view not ajax request.

}
```